# Row level permission for admin page using django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my project i am having few stores and for each store there is one particular owner as well.
I wanted to assign those stores to the particular owners. No other should have the permission to update the data corresponding to that store. All owners will have the admin privileges to access that particular set of data.

Comment: please post some relevant code to your question.

Comment: There is only a simple model class . I wanted to know whether this can be done or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parts involved:

1. filtering
2. permission

For filtering, you have to override `get_queryset` for every Viewset/APIView. For example,

```
def get_queryset(self):
    # you can do anything here
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    return qs.filter(owner=self.user)
```

For permission, it's depending on how you are going to do that. The safest bet is to implement `restframework.permissions` which you can even go at object level. Then you can set in `settings.py` like

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'core.permissions.IsStoreOwnerOrNoModification',
    ]
}
```

Comment: could you share how the default permission class is implemented.